# Python error reading space delimited file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read the file text.txt in python which contains the line:

```
c]pyridin -0.094498 -0.036198 -0.107498 0.205711
```

With csv reader:

```
with open('text.txt','r') as file:
    reader=csv.reader(file,delimiter=' ')
    doc=list(reader)
```

When executing the following:

```
for line in doc:
    print line[0]
```

I expect:

```
c]pyridin
```

but instead get:

```
c]pyridin -0.094498 -0.036198 -0.107498 0.205711
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the delimiter is a _single_ space - multiple spaces are not handled by default. Is it possible that they are tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way I did this try this:

```
 t= path/filename.txt
 f = open(t,'r')
 content = f.read()
 fieldsInline = content.split(" ")
 print fieldsInline[1]
 f.close()
```